The method requestMatchers in the type AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
I'm doing spring boot web application with SQL Server 2019. Now I'm trying to do JWT Authentication & Authorization with Spring Security but my SecurityConfig.java have error with requestMatchers:

The method requestMatchers(RequestMatcher...) in the type AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry<AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)Java(67108979)

I don't know why this happen because I see a lot of people use requestMatchers and run well with no red line above it.
Here is
SecurityConfig.java:
package com.example.demologin.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.example.demologin.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import com.example.demologin.service.UserDetailsServiceImp;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImp userDetailsServiceImp;

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    private final CustomLogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImp userDetailsServiceImp,
                          JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter,
                          CustomLogoutHandler logoutHandler) {
        this.userDetailsServiceImp = userDetailsServiceImp;
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
        this.logoutHandler = logoutHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        req->req.requestMatchers("/login/**","/register/**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/admin_only/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                ).userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImp)
                .sessionManagement(session->session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling(
                        e->e.accessDeniedHandler(
                                        (request, response, accessDeniedException)->response.setStatus(403)
                                )
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
                .logout(l->l
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
                        ))
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


}

Here is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demologin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demologin</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.jre11</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Here is my complete src code : https://github.com/phuccoder/demojwt.git

And I already change to antMatchers, but I test localhost:8080/register or any url, it give me 403 status.


You will be fine using either

req.antMatchers("/login", "/register")
req.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/register"))

in your SecurityConfig.securityFilterChain().
The reason you are getting 403 status code using antMatchers is because the way you implemented the JwtAuthenticationFilter you always require an Authorization header and if you don't provide it you will get a NullPointerException which leads to the error.
There probably are some logic flaws in your implementation, such as requiring both registration and login to be authenticated (i.e. if the user is not yet registered, how can he be authenticated?) or the JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal() immediately returning when detecting Authorization: Bearer header (which is not what you want maybe).
Furthermore, there surely is a bug in AuthenticationService.register() :
you do user.setRole(user.getRole()) while you should do user.setRole(request.getRole())
